# Subtract a value returns double instead of int

Tags: xslt-2.0

I want to output something n times. Therefore I wanted to use for-each like this

```
<xsl:variable name="count" select="string-length(data/key)" />
<xsl:for-each select="1 to $count">X</xsl:for-each>
```

This works well, but if I want to subtract a number from string-length

```
<xsl:variable name="count" select="string-length(data/key) - 3" />
```

the compiler gives me a "required type is xs:integer, but got xs:double"

I tried setting the variable type

```
<xsl:variable name="count" select="string-length(data/key) - 3" as="xs:integer" />
```

to variable declaration but the error remains.

When I output the variable value

```
<xsl:value-of select="$count" />
```

I get an integer value. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce the issue, when I run

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">


<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="count" select="string-length(data/key) - 3" />
  <xsl:for-each select="1 to $count">X</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with Saxon 9.5 against

```
<data>
  <key>Kibology</key>
</data>
```

I get the output `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>XXXXX`.

Please post a minimal but complete sample allowing us to reproduce the problem, of course telling us which XSLT 2.0 processor you used.

Comment: AS I found out now, I referenced the wrong XSLT-version in xsl:stylesheet. Funnily I used some features of version 2 before without having any issues.

Comment: Most new stuff functions well within a `version="1.0"` stylesheet executed by an XSLT 2.0 processor but, if supported, the processor works in backwards compatible mode http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#backwards and for instance treats numbers with the only type that existed in XPath/XSLT 1.0, namely the double type.

Comment: Couldn't be the whole truth. Try the above example with version "1.0" and without the "-3" and you'll get no double-error.

Comment: Sorry, I mainly linked to the spec to allow you to read the details, the comment in itself is not meant as a precise description of backwards compatible processing.